# Phone number formatting in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

In my app, the user enters his phone number. 
For example, If he enters: 
 123456 
I want him to see:
 12 34 56
How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Try this its working based on locale :

```
etNumber.addTextChangedListener(new PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher());
```

You can also use with country code. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberFormattingTextWatcher.html

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on the `PhoneNumberUtils` in the `android.telephony` API: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneNumberUtils.html

Edit:

There you find the method `formatNumber` which you can use to display the phone number.

This method tries to format the number according to the rules for the country it is from. If this isn't possible it return the raw number.

```
public static String formatNumber (String phoneNumber)
```

This method tries to format the number according the given country's default convention (the country parameter is to set with a two letter country code like `US`, `GB` or `DE`. For further information look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1). If the number is not valid the method return `null`.

```
public static String formatNumber (String phoneNumber, String defaultCountryIso)
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. I hope now it is complete enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can add text watcher to your edit text and check the size of text till 2 place and add space in it like as follows

```
callphoneEditText.addTextChangedListener(new CustomTextWatcherForPhoneNumber());
```

The following class does the required thing you needed

```
  public static class CustomTextWatcherForPhoneNumber implements TextWatcher {

        // Change this to what you want... ' ', '-' etc..
        private static final char space = ' ';

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // Remove spacing char
            if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
                final char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                if (space == c) {
                    s.delete(s.length() - 1, s.length());
                }
            }
            // Insert char where needed.
            if (s.length() > 0 && (s.length() % 5) == 0) {
                char c = s.charAt(s.length() - 1);
                // Only if its a digit where there should be a space we insert a
                // space
                if (Character.isDigit(c)
                        && TextUtils.split(s.toString(), String.valueOf(space)).length <= 2) { ****// At this point you will check values and add space between them****
                    s.insert(s.length() - 1, String.valueOf(space));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Check it and let me know if it is helpful to you or not

Answer (score 0):

you can look at libphonenumber library from google code.
https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber.

I did a small app using that for android and it works pretty well.

The XX XX XX XX number format is usually used in France. so you can do something like

```
String formattedNumber = phoneUtil.parse(numberProto, "FR");
```

They also have a 'format as you type' feature, which may be what you are interested in too. do check out their examples.

```
//Formatting Phone Numbers 'as you type'

PhoneNumberUtil phoneUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance();
AsYouTypeFormatter formatter = phoneUtil.getAsYouTypeFormatter("US");
System.out.println(formatter.inputDigit('6'));  // Outputs "6"
...  // Input more digits
System.out.println(formatter.inputDigit('3'));  // Now outputs "650 253"
```

**edit**

you can use the link below https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html to try out what the code returns. (of interest is the output of the "asYouTypeFormatter"

[image]

Comment: The format as you type feature is broken in that library for international numbers (https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). It doesn't actually do any formatting

Comment: @portfoliobuilder, it should be working. you can look at the unittests below for more details on how the formatter is to be used. https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/blob/master/java/libphonenumber/test/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/AsYouTypeFormatterTest.java.

Comment: Is the unit test a comprehensive list? If so, then that is the reason why "FR" for France does not work. It is not supported.

Comment: @portfoliobuilder, This library is meant to be international, it should work for France. you can try the online version that uses the same library at https://rawgit.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber/master/javascript/i18n/phonenumbers/demo-compiled.html. If it is not working, do file a bug report to them with the numbers you use for testing. (see my edit in the post).